# prepareForSegue after UISearchDisplayController

Tags: storyboard, didselectrowatindexpath, searchdisplaycontroller

EDIT:

I just found: [How to segue from a UISearchBarDisplayController result to a detailViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325103/how-to-segue-from-a-uisearchbardisplaycontroller-result-to-a-detailviewcontrolle)

which I'll take a look at!

---

I'm combining a 'search bar and search display controller' with core data fetchedResultsController using storyboard. That is, I have to differentiate between:

```
if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    ...
```

and the case where I've just listed the results fetched from the data store.

However, I'm having trouble getting the right row (index path) in the following case:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"StoreDetails"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        StoreDetailsTableViewController *controller = (StoreDetailsTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        Store *storeToDetail = nil;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];  // This gives wrong row when having searched using searchDisplayController
        NSLog(@"Row: %i", indexPath.row);                                                   // row is always 0
        if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            storeToDetail = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            storeToDetail = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

         controller.storeToDetail = storeToDetail;
    }
}
```

which is called after:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller       shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:@"All"];
    ...
```

with:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects];

    for (Store *store in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
    {
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [store.name isEqualToString:scope])
        {
            NSComparisonResult result = [store.name compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:store];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is taken from Apple's TableSearch example.

The original problem is twofold:

1) self.tableView doesn't seem to be equal to self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView is prepareForSegue

2) having searched the indexPath (row) is always 0.

I suppose I could use didSelectRow... instead or in combination, but I believe prepare... should be possible?! Also, when experimenting with didSelectRow... I'm sure how to pass the object from the relevant row to the destination controller. That is, I can get the correct indexPath in didSelectRow... but I only know how to get the segue destination in the preparFor...:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    Store *storeToDetail = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        storeToDetail = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        storeToDetail = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    // How to get segue destination controller and set object?!
    // Before doing:
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"StoreDetails" sender:self];
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Maybe a reference to a tutorial which shows how to combine theses things.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In this case the `sender`argument of `prepareForSegue:sender:` is set to the table view cell initiating the segue.

Just add a property to your cells that holds the `Store` belonging to this cell and you don't have to do any of the index path or table view comparison dance.

You should end up with something as simple as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FooCell *cell = (FooCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
    Foo *foo = [self fooForIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.foo = foo;
    // additional initialization

    return cell;
}
```

and

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"view detail"]) {
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.foo = [(FooCell *)sender foo];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. my. gosh. You just changed my life.

I just added a dataID parameter to my UITableViewCell subclass (which was already further subclassed for every cell in my project), and now, as you said, I don't need to worry about those annoying index paths or table view comparisons anymore!

I really wish I could up vote this more than once.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

if(self.filteredListContent)

{//NSLog(@"post filtered data";}

else

{//NSLog(@"post all";}

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong test.

```
if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
  ...
```

This will always fail, you are asking if two different tableViews are different.  The answer is always no.

However, you can test if the sender is from the searchResultsTableView.

```
NSIndexPath *searchIndexPathOfSelectedCell = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForCell:sender];

if (searchIndexPathOfSelectedCell) {
  ...
```